# how to exchange key and value to sort in ascending order in java using hadoop map reduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I want to have an output with the number of visits sorted in ascending order using only mapper and reducer class
I want to exchange the key and value in the output of the mapper so that it sorts it automatically and then exchange them again in the reducer

However, I am having trouble with the type of data I am supposed to use.

Here is the mapper :

```
extends
        Mapper<LongWritable, Text, IntWritable, Text> 
{
    public void map(LongWritable cle, Text valeur, Context sortie)
            throws IOException          
    {
        
        String url = "";
        int nbVisites = 0;
        Pattern httplogPattern = Pattern.compile("([^\\s]+) - - \\[(.+)\\] \"([^\\s]+) (/[^\\s]*) HTTP/[^\\s]+\" [^\\s]+ ([0-9]+)");
        String ligne = valeur.toString();

        //if (ligne.length()>0) {
        Matcher matcher = httplogPattern.matcher(ligne);
        if (matcher.matches()) {
                    url = matcher.group(1);
                    nbVisites++;
        
                Text urlText = new Text(url);
                IntWritable value = new IntWritable(nbVisites);
                try 
                {           
                    sortie.write(value, urlText);   
                    System.out.println(urlText + " ; " + value);
                } 
                catch (InterruptedException e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
    }
        //}
        }
```

Reducer :

```
        Reducer<IntWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> 
{
    
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context sortie) throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
        
        Iterator<IntWritable> it = values.iterator();
        int nb = 0;
        while (it.hasNext()) {
                 nb = nb + it.next().get();
                }
    

            

        try {
            
            sortie.write(key, new IntWritable(nb));
            
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        
    
}
```

And main class :

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
  {
    Job job = new Job();
    
    job.setJobName("TP4");
    
    job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);
    
    job.setOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

    job.setMapperClass(WordCountMapper.class);        
    job.setReducerClass(WordCountReducer.class);

    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, args[0]);
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

    FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(job.getConfiguration());
    fs.delete(new Path(args[1]));
                
    job.waitForCompletion(true);
  }
```

Here is the file :

each line contains an url and we count the number of times we ecounter the url in the file

```
199.72.81.55 - - [01/Jul/1995:00:00:01 -0400] "GET /history/apollo/ HTTP/1.0" 200 6245
unicomp6.unicomp.net - - [01/Jul/1995:00:00:06 -0400] "GET /shuttle/countdown/ HTTP/1.0" 200 3985
199.120.110.21 - - [01/Jul/1995:00:00:09 -0400] "GET /shuttle/missions/sts-73/mission-sts-73.html HTTP/1.0" 200 4085
burger.letters.com - - [01/Jul/1995:00:00:11 -0400] "GET /shuttle/countdown/liftoff.html HTTP/1.0" 304 0
199.120.110.21 - - [01/Jul/1995:00:00:11 -0400] "GET /shuttle/missions/sts-73/sts-73-patch-small.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 4179
burger.letters.com - - [01/Jul/1995:00:00:12 -0400] "GET /images/NASA-logosmall.gif HTTP/1.0" 304 0
burger.letters.com - - [01/Jul/1995:00:00:12 -0400] "GET /shuttle/countdown/video/livevideo.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 0
```

Here is the output i currently have:

```
1   199.72.81.55
1   unicomp6.unicomp.net
1   199.120.110.21
1   burger.letters.com
1   199.120.110.21
1   burger.letters.com
1   burger.letters.com
1   205.212.115.106
1   d104.aa.net
1   129.94.144.152
1   unicomp6.unicomp.net
1   unicomp6.unicomp.net
1   unicomp6.unicomp.net
1   d104.aa.net
1   d104.aa.net
1   d104.aa.net
```

I want this output in ascending order :

```
129.94.144.152  1
199.72.81.55    1
205.212.115.106 1
199.120.110.21  2
burger.letters.com  3
d104.aa.net 4
unicomp6.unicomp.net    4
```

Comment: The code you provided shouldn't compile since your reduce method has the wrong types

Answer (score 0):

Force all data to one reducer using a NullWritable. Then you can sort all values using a `TreeMap` from the reducer

```
public class WebLogDriver extends Configured implements Tool {

  public static final String APP_NAME = WebLogDriver.class.getSimpleName();

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final int status = ToolRunner.run(new Configuration(), new WebLogDriver(), args);
    System.exit(status);
  }

  @Override
  public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = getConf();
    Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, APP_NAME);
    job.setJarByClass(WebLogDriver.class);

    // outputs for mapper and reducer
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);

    // setup mapper
    job.setMapperClass(WebLogDriver.WebLogMapper.class);
    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(NullWritable.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);

    // setup reducer
    job.setReducerClass(WebLogDriver.WebLogReducer.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    final Path outputDir = new Path(args[1]);
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, outputDir);

    return job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1;
  }

  static class WebLogMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, NullWritable, Text> {

    static final Pattern HTTP_LOG_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("(\\S+) - - \\[(.+)] \"(\\S+) (/\\S*) HTTP/\\S+\" \\S+ (\\d+)");

    final Text valueOut = new Text();

    @Override
    protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Mapper<LongWritable, Text, NullWritable, Text>.Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      String line = value.toString();
      if (line.isEmpty()) {
        return;
      }
      Matcher matcher = HTTP_LOG_PATTERN.matcher(line);

      if (matcher.matches()) {
        String url = matcher.group(1);
        valueOut.set(String.format("%s,%d", url, 1); // count each host once

        context.write(NullWritable.get(), valueOut);
      }
    }
  }

  static class WebLogReducer extends Reducer<NullWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

    static final Text keyOut = new Text();
    static final IntWritable valueOut = new IntWritable();

    @Override
    protected void reduce(NullWritable key, Iterable<Text> values, Reducer<NullWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable>.Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      // builds in ascending order by default
      Map<String, Integer> m = new TreeMap<>();
      for (Text t : values) {
        String v = new String(t.getBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        String[] parts = v.split(",");

        String host = parts[0];
        int count = m.getOrDefault(host, 0) + Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
        m.put(host, count);
      }

      for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> e : m.entrySet()) {
        keyOut.set(e.getKey());
        valueOut.set(e.getValue());
        context.write(keyOut, valueOut);
      }
    }
  }
}
```